# How can I change my ffmpeg command to hardcode the second subtitles stream?

Tags: ffmpeg

My command is

```
ffmpeg -i "a.mkv" -vf subtitles="a.mkv" -acodec copy "a.mp4"
```

which burns the first one by default

I want to burn the second subtitles stream, not the first (there's two included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the stream index.

```
ffmpeg -i "a.mkv" -vf subtitles="a.mkv":si=1 -acodec copy "a.mp4"
```

---

To omit the first audio stream.

```
ffmpeg -i "a.mkv" -vf subtitles="a.mkv":si=1 -acodec copy -map 0 -map -0:a:0 "a.mp4"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot a detail, could you please also tell me how to select the second audio stream instead of the first one (in addition to the 2nd subtitles stream) ?